# Block until a reader has connected to named pipe

Tags: c, linux, fifo

I've written a server which opens a named pipe (which blocks, so it waits until a client is connected), and then periodically writes something to the pipe. The client opens the pipe, reads from it and processes the data. However, due to circumstances I can't control, the client frequently exits and is restarted again soon thereafter.

This causes problems when the server wants to write something in the short interval when there is no reader connected to the pipe: the server receives a SIGPIPE and exits. I can ignore the signal, but I don't want to lose the data: ideally, the server would wait until the client has reconnected to the pipe before writing the data. It's no problem for the server to block during this write.

Using `write()` I can try a 0-byte write and check for a `EPIPE` error to detect whether there is a client connected. But how can I block until a client is connected (aside from sleeping a bit, and trying the write again)?

Or is there another, better way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it practical to close and reopen the pipe?

Comment: Did you try to [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Even with `poll()`, the pipe may get ready for writing, and then, just before you write, the reader dies: you have lost data!

Comment: I believe you have to accept that you could lose some data.... Or change the protocol (to require the client to acknowledge the received data).

Comment: The root of the problem here is that a small `write()` (less than `fpathconf(pipefd,_PC_PATH_MAX)` bytes) will succeed, even if the corresponding `read()` was smaller, with no way for the writer to find out if the `read()` was smaller. If it was, any difference (tail end of data) is always lost. Whether the named pipe (FIFO) is nonblocking or not does not change the issue.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: you probably mean `PIPE_MAX` not `PATH_MAX` ...

Comment: Thanks, @BasileStarynkevitch! Yes, it should be `_PC_PIPE_BUF`, obviously, as described by [`man 3 fpathconf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpathconf.3.html). And I agree with recommending a protocol change. Personally, perhaps to using [Unix domain datagram sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) with sequence number and length at the start. When a client connects, send the latest packet automatically, but also let the client request restart at specific packet by sending the sequence number. Should let even narcoleptic clients keep up..

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Apparently `poll()` (or `select()` for that matter) doesn't work in this case because `write()` does not really block in the case of a broken pipe (it returns immediately with `EPIPE`). Thus a broken pipe might meet the definition of "ready for write without blocking". My tests point to that direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that contrary to my comment to the original question above, there is a straightforward solution.

This solution assumes that all readers and all writers to the same FIFO share the kernel buffers. This should be the most logical and straightforward way to implement FIFOs (considering their behaviour), so I do expect all systems providing FIFOs to behave this way. However, it is just my assumption, not any guarantee. I have not found anything in the relevant POSIX standards to support or contradict this. Please do pipe up if you find otherwise.

The procedure is trivial:

When a client vanishes unexpectedly, the writer opens the FIFO again, without closing the original descriptor first. This `open()` will block, until there is a new reader available, but since the original file descriptor is still open, the data already buffered in the FIFO will be available to the new reader. If the `open()` succeeds, the writer simply closes the original descriptor, and switches to using the new descriptor instead.

If the kernel structures are shared, the FIFO buffer state is shared between the writer descriptors, and the new reader will be able to read what the previous reader left unread.

(Note that the writer does not know the amount of data buffered between client changes, and is therefore unaware of the point in data stream where the switch happens.)

I have verified this trivial strategy works on Linux 3.8.0-35-generic kernels on x86_64 in Ubuntu, as well as 2.6.9-104.ELsmp on x86_64.

---

However, I still fully agree with either accepting the data loss, or changing the protocol, as suggested by Basile Starynkevitch in a comment to the original question.

Personally, I have found Unix domain sockets (bound to a pathname, say `/var/run/yourservice/unix`) to be a much better option, because it allows multiple simultaneous clients without data corruption (unlike FIFOs), and a much saner protocol.

I prefer Unix datagram sockets, with a sequence number and datagram length at the start of each datagram. (The length helps the client verify it read the entire datagram; I don't really expect any OS to truncate Unix datagrams.)

Typically, the writer sends a few datagrams to each client, and waits for acknowledgement before sending new ones. After processing a datagram, the client acknowledges the datagram by sending the sequence number to the writer. (Remember, these are sockets, so the communication is bidirectional.) This allows the writer to keep a few datagrams in flight per client, and the client to process the datagrams in either correct (sequence number) order, or out-of-order, using multiple threads.

The important point being that each datagram is acknowledged only after it has been processed, not immediately after it has been received.

(In addition to reader->writer "acks" (acknowledgements), I would also support "please resend" responses, in case the client used a too small buffer to receive a datagram. Or dropped it on the floor due to some other reasons. And maybe even "yuck" for datagrams the client does not know what to do about.)

If a client vanishes, the writer *knows* that all un-acknowledged datagrams were not processed by the client yet, and can re-send them to another connected client, or a future client.

Questions?

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right, so after some more consideration I've chosen to implement a socket-based protocol instead (which works great).

Comment: You allude to fifo corruption with multiple clients. Do you have any references to further information please?

Comment: @lane: I don't recall (or see, after re-reading my answer above) any connection to *corruption* here, only to data loss. As I explained above, I verified this solution experimentally myself (after examining the Linux kernel implementation of named pipes), so I'm not sure what kind of references to further information you mean or are interested in.

Comment: Okay, my bad - I obviously read too much into "..because it allows multiple simultaneous clients without data corruption (unlike FIFOs)...".

Comment: @lane: Ah, *that*. See [`man 7 pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), the `PIPE_BUF` section. If two processes write to the same pipe (or FIFO) in chunks larger than `PIPE_BUF`, the writes may be interleaved. This means that if you have multiple writers on the same FIFO, their large writes may be interleaved. This is data corruption. With sockets, you can create a separate socket pair between the reader and each writer, so this kind of interleaving does not occur, regardless of the chunk size. (By *chunk*, I refer to the amount of data in each `write()` call.)

Comment: Very good answer, although this smells like a hack. Worth of notice: in Linux, one can use `/proc/self/fd/<n>` as a path to the `open()` call in order to "reopen" a pipe associated with fd `n`.

Comment: @Alek: I'm fully aware; I just don't see any sensible way how you could use the `/proc/PID/fd/FD` pseudofiles in OP's situation. Note that OP explicitly wants to use a named pipe, so getting a handle to the pipe is not the problem. The problem is how to let a new client read the already written but unread data in the named pipe, while having the writer in a known, reliable state. I do consider the approach I outlined above a bit of a hack -- as I explicitly mention, it's not backed by POSIX, and thus may not work on all POSIXy systems -- but it is the one with the best probability of working.